# Descriptive model theory classification of Counting hierarchy

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, descriptive-complexity, finite-model-theory, model-theory

Descriptive model theory uses logic to characterize complexity classes

How to model

1. Counting Hierarchy
2. PSPACE

in descriptive model theory?

Answer (score 5):

This is only a partial answer (to the $PSPACE$ characterization), but I don't have the reputation to comment.

$PSPACE$ has the following (equivalent) descriptive characterizations:

1. $FO[2^{n^{O(1)}}]$, first-order logic with exponentially iterated quantifier blocks.
2. $SO[n^{O(1)}]$, second-order logic with polynomially iterated quantifier blocks.
3. $SO[TC]$, second-order logic with a transitive closure operator.
4. $FO[PFP]$, first-order logic with a partial fixed point operator.
5. $CRAM$-$PROC[2^{n^{O(1)}}, n^{O(1)}]$, concurrent-read concurrent-write random access machine with exponential time and polynomial hardware.
6. $CRAM$-$PROC[n^{O(1)}, 2^{n^{O(1)}}]$, concurrent-read concurrent-write with polynomial time and exponential hardware.

These are all mentioned in Immerman's book *Descriptive Complexity*.

I can't find a reference on a descriptive characterization for the counting hierarchy, but here are some observations:

- $PP$ naturally corresponds to existential second-order logic with a second-order majority quantifier.
- $TC^0$ is equal to $FO$ with a majority quantifier. Padding arguments give us a relationship between $TC^0$ and $CH$. This relationship makes $SO$ with a majority quantifier (on relations) a natural candidate for a descriptive characterization of $CH$.

Comment: It should, however, be mentioned that characterisations 1 and 4 only hold for properties of ordered structures. But for example not for graphs. E.g., whether an  graph without edges has an even number of nodes cannot be expressed in FO[PFP]. 2 and 3 should work, though.

Comment: @SamMcGuire Then $\oplus P$ is existential $SO$ logic with $SO$ parity quantifier?